# How do you restore the result of each iteration of a for loop into its own matrix?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, seurat

I have a for loop that takes each sample file on a list, creates a matrix for that sample, and then stores it into one big list of all the sample matrices.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
# load in data ------------------------------------------------------------------

filePaths = getGEOSuppFiles("GSE124395") 
tarF <- list.files(path = "./GSE124395/", pattern = "*.tar", full.names = TRUE) 
untar(tarF, exdir = "./GSE124395/") 
gzipF <- list.files(path = "./GSE124395/", pattern = "*.gz", full.names = TRUE) 
ldply(.data = gzipF, .fun = gunzip) 

#running test loop -------------------------------------------------------------

testlist <- c("./GSE124395//GSM3531672_P301_3_CRYOMIXED11.coutt.csv", 
 "./GSE124395//GSM3531673_P301_4_CRYOMIXED12.coutt.csv",
"./GSE124395//GSM3531674_P301_5_HEP1_1_5.coutt.csv")

LoopList_test <- list()

for (i in 1:length(testlist)){
  
  matrix_test <- read.delim(file =testlist[i])
  matrix_test <- data.frame(matrix_test[,-1], row.names=matrix_test[,1]) 
  matrix_test <- as.matrix(matrix_test) #<- makes the excel file into a matrix 
  
  colname_test <- read.delim(file =testlist[i])
  colname_test <- read.table(file = './GSE124395//GSE124395_celseq_barcodes.192.txt', header = FALSE, row.names = 1) 
  colname_test <- data.frame(colname_test[,-1], col=colname_test[,1]) 
  colname_test <- as.matrix(colname_test) 
  colnames(matrix_test) <- colname_test[,1] 
  
  LoopList_test[[i]]<-matrix_test
}
```

This is the output:
[part of output in the one big list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGu3h.png)

I would like the loop to store the result of each iteration into its own matrix, so I have multiple matrices instead of one giant list of matrices, if that makes sense. I think it involves either splitting this one giant list into sublists, or storing the results of the loop into a matrix/array/vector instead of a list, or somehow having it store each iteration into its own variable within the loop. I'm not sure how to go about doing any of those.

Thanks for reading!

UPDATE:

So the whole point of this was to create matrices to then combine them into one matrix. Then turn this one matrix into a Seurat object which I could then perform clustering on.

So here is what I have done so far: essentially, I made multiple loops of each group within the dataset, added whatever information I needed, and then took the list and the function I think I need actually takes a list so that's good for me. Here's the code I decided on at the moment:

```
mylist<-list.files(path = "./GSE124395/", pattern = "\\.csv$",full.names = TRUE)

LoopList <- list()

for (i in 1:30){
  
  matrix_input <- read.delim(file =mylist[i])
  matrix_input <- data.frame(matrix_input[,-1], row.names=matrix_input[,1]) 
  matrix_input <- as.matrix(matrix_input) #<- makes the excel file into a matrix 
  
  colname_input <- read.delim(file =mylist[i])
  colname_input <- read.table(file = './GSE124395//GSE124395_celseq_barcodes.192.txt', header = FALSE, row.names = 1) 
  colname_input <- data.frame(colname_input[,-1], col=colname_input[,1]) 
  colname_input <- as.matrix(colname_input) 
  colnames(matrix_input) <- colname_input[,1] 
  
  colnames(matrix_input) <- paste(colnames(matrix_input), "Colorectal_Metastasis", sep = "_")
  P301_pdat <- data.frame("samples" = colnames(matrix_input), "treatment" = "Colorectal_Metastasis") 
  
  sobj <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = matrix_input, min.cells = 0, min.features = 1, 
                             project = "Patient301_Colorectal_Metastasis")
  
  LoopList[[i]]<-sobj
  #LoopList <- assign(paste0("Patient301", i), sobj )
}



# P304 loop ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 


for (i in 31:56){
  
  matrix_input <- read.delim(file =mylist[i])
  matrix_input <- data.frame(matrix_input[,-1], row.names=matrix_input[,1]) 
  matrix_input <- as.matrix(matrix_input) #<- makes the excel file into a matrix 
  
  colname_input <- read.delim(file =mylist[i])
  colname_input <- read.table(file = './GSE124395//GSE124395_celseq_barcodes.192.txt', header = FALSE, row.names = 1) 
  colname_input <- data.frame(colname_input[,-1], col=colname_input[,1]) 
  colname_input <- as.matrix(colname_input) 
  colnames(matrix_input) <- colname_input[,1] 
  
  colnames(matrix_input) <- paste(colnames(matrix_input), "Colorectal_Metastasis", sep = "_")
  P304_pdat <- data.frame("samples" = colnames(matrix_input), "treatment" = "Colorectal_Metastasis") 
  
  sobj <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = matrix_input, min.cells = 0, min.features = 1, 
                             project = "Patient304_Colorectal_Metastasis")
  
  LoopList[[i]]<-sobj
  
}
```

and so on. Then, following https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/integration_large_datasets.html

```
sobj.list <- SplitObject(LoopList, split.by = "orig.ident")
joined <- lapply(X = LoopList, FUN = function(x) {
  x <- NormalizeData(x, verbose = FALSE)
  x <- FindVariableFeatures(x, verbose = FALSE)
})


features <- SelectIntegrationFeatures(object.list = joined)
joined <- lapply(X = joined, FUN = function(x) {
  x <- ScaleData(x, features = features, verbose = FALSE)
  x <- RunPCA(x, features = features, verbose = FALSE)
})


anchors <- FindIntegrationAnchors(object.list = joined, reduction = "rpca", 
                                  dims = 1:50)
joined.integrated <- IntegrateData(anchorset = anchors, dims = 1:50)

joined.integrated <- ScaleData(joined.integrated, verbose = FALSE)
joined.integrated <- RunPCA(joined.integrated, verbose = FALSE)
joined.integrated <- RunUMAP(joined.integrated, dims = 1:50)

DimPlot(joined.integrated, group.by = "orig.ident")
DimPlot(joined.integrated, reduction = "umap", split.by = "treatment")
```

I don't know if this works for sure, but I thought I would update this question to reflect what I've learned so far! I guess lesson I've learned is see if you can find a function that takes a list as input heh.

Comment: Instead of `LoopList_test[[i]]<-matrix_test` try `assign(paste0("LoopList_test", i), matrix_test )`

Comment: Good to hear this worked!

Comment: So actually it didn't work unfortunately @kukuk1de :( It didn't retain all the rows of each individual matrix